# What module I can use instead of ColorBar in Bokeh v0.12.13

Tags: python, bokeh

I was trying to write script using ColorBar module following the [official document.](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#color-bars)
However,I got error below.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ColorBar'
```

Also, when I look at the bokeh github page, module ColorBar is not provided anymore.
Does anyone know how following code should be revised to be compatible with v0.12.13?

```
def heatmap(df,colstr):
    from math import pi
    from bokeh.io import show
    from bokeh.models import (
        ColorBar,
        ColumnDataSource,
        HoverTool,
        LinearColorMapper,
        BasicTicker,
        PrintfTickFormatter,
    )
    from bokeh.plotting import figure

    def preprocess(df,colstr):
        #temp=pd.DataFrame(df[colstr])
        df["Hour"]=df.index.hour.astype(str)
        df["Date"]=df.index.date.astype(str)
        temp=df[["Hour","Date",colstr]]

        return temp

    #add hour column and day column
    df1=preprocess(df,colstr)

    colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
    mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=df[colstr].min(), high=df[colstr].max())

    source = ColumnDataSource(df1)
    #hard cord. better to be flexiable
    hours = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23']
    #assuming  summerdesign day and winter design day is included
    #dates = list(df1["Date"])[48:]
    dates = list(df1["Date"].drop_duplicates())[4:]

    TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"

    p = figure(title=colstr,
               x_range=hours, y_range=list(reversed(dates)),
               x_axis_location="above", plot_width=1200, plot_height=1200,
              tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below')

    p.grid.grid_line_color = None
    p.axis.axis_line_color = None
    p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
    p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "5pt"
    p.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi / 3

    p.rect(x="Hour", y="Date", width=1, height=1,
           source=source,
           fill_color={'field': colstr, 'transform': mapper},
           line_color=None)


    color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, major_label_text_font_size="5pt",
                         ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)),
                         formatter=PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d%%"),
                         label_standoff=6, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))
    p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')


    p.select_one(HoverTool).tooltips = [
         ('date', '@Date'),
         ('hour', '@Hour'),
    ]

    show(p)      # show the plot
```

Answer (score 0):

`ColorBar` is still there: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.13/bokeh/models/annotations.py#L197

And importing it via `bokeh.models.ColorBar` is still working for me on multiple installations on different machines.

The most likely cause is that you don't actually run this code with Bokeh 0.12.13 (although I'm not sure how old the Bokeh installation has to be to not have `ColorBar` model), or your installation is somehow got corrupt.